# Is the product of distances to a point convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, products

Let the distance from point $a$ to point $x_i$ be the $L_2$ norm,

\begin{align} 
\|a - x_i\|_2
\end{align}

This is a convex function in $a$.

Are the following functions convex in $a$ on $a \geq 0$?

\begin{align}
\Pi_{i=1}^N \|a - x_i\|_2
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
a * \Pi_{i=1}^N \|a - x_i\|_2
\end{align}

And why?

Comment: In general, no. Take $x_k = 0$, $N=2$. The function $a \mapsto |a-1||a+1|$ is not convex, it has zeroes at $\pm 1$ but has value one at $a=0$.

Comment: Mmm but I'm looking specifically at $a \geq 0$, i.e. the positive orthant of $a$.

Comment: Am I just having trouble doing algebra because it is late at night, or is it not $a^2 - 1$?

Comment: If $|a|< 1$ then $|a^2-1| = 1- a^2$. Try specific values, like $0, {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, clearly too late at night.  Mind adding this as a reply so that I can accept it and close the question?

Comment: Try some wine. I find it helps :-).

Comment: An easy way to see it: when $a$ equals any of the $x_i$, the product of distances is zero, but everywhere else, the product of distances is positive. Take $a$ to be a convex combination of two $x_i$ and this immediately contradicts the definition of convexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $N=2$, $x_1=1,x_2 = -1$, then for $|a| \le 1$ we have
$|a-1||a+1| = |a^2-1| = 1-a^2$ which is not a convex function of $a$.